# Relacionamento entre dois ComboBox no Acess

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Estou tentando relacionar 2 ComboBoxes no Acess, porém não consigo encontrar como fazer isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é meu formulário, gostaria que ao selecionar o valor no campo "Tipo de Despesa", os valores do campo abaixo, "Despesa", fossem relacionados ao campo "Tipo de despesa":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, ao selecionar "FIXO" no "Tipo de despesa", os valores disponíveis no campo "Despesa" fossem somente o "FIXO" e caso eu selecione "VARIÁVEL", a lista do campo "Despesa" mudaria para os valores relacionados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualmente esta lista está aparecendo em ambos os casos, "FIXO" ou "VARIÁVEL", porém gostaria de fazer de alguma forma condicional, para que dependendo do valor selecionado em "Tipo de despesa" sua respectiva lista apareça no campo abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Oi, Dimitri!

Essa pergunta foi a 3 meses, então provavelmente já foi resolvida, mas pra deixar registrado aqui, uma das formas de fazer isso é usando o evento _change do seu combobox que tem a hierarquia mais alta, neste caso tipo de despesa.

Aí existem muitas formas de fazer isso, você pode deixar o campo vazio e ao selecionar usar um combobox.additem, mas aí você precisa excluir quando mudar a seleção, pode colocar um rowsource que seja uma tabela com where e você muda o campo cada escolha (denovo _change), você pode popular de um vetor e por aí vai.